# Combine result from top_n with an "Other" category in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame **dat1**

```
   Country Count
1      AUS     1
2       NZ     2
3       NZ     1
4      USA     3
5      AUS     1
6      IND     2
7      AUS     4
8      USA     2
9      JPN     5
10      CN     2
```

First I want to sum "Count" per "Country". Then the top 3 total counts per  country should be combined with an additional row "Others", which is the sum of countries which are not part of top 3.

The expected outcome therefore would be:

```
    Country Count
1     AUS     6
2     JPN     5
3     USA     5
4     Others  7
```

I have tried the below code, but could not figure out how to place the "Others" row.

```
dat1 %>%
    group_by(Country) %>%
    summarise(Count = sum(Count)) %>%
    arrange(desc(Count)) %>%
    top_n(3)
```

This code currently gives:

```
    Country Count
1     AUS     6
2     JPN     5
3     USA     5
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
dat1 <- structure(list(Country = structure(c(1L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 
    1L, 6L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("AUS", "CN", "IND", "JPN", "NZ", 
    "USA"), class = "factor"), Count = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    4L, 2L, 5L, 2L)), .Names = c("Country", "Count"), class = "data.frame",     row.names = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: Related Q&A: [Creating an “other” field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730067/creating-an-other-field]).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of `top_n`, this seems like a good case for the convenience function `tally`. It uses `summarise`, `sum` and `arrange` under the hood.

Then use `factor` to create an "Other" category. Use the `levels` argument to set "Other" as the last level. "Other" will then will be placed last in the table (and in any subsequent plot of the result).

If "Country" is `factor` in your original data, you may wrap `Country[1:3]` in `as.character`.

```
group_by(df, Country) %>%
  tally(Count, sort = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(Country = factor(c(Country[1:3], rep("Other", n() - 3)),
                            levels = c(Country[1:3], "Other"))) %>%
  tally(n) 

#  Country     n
#   (fctr) (int)
#1     AUS     6
#2     JPN     5
#3     USA     5
#4   Other     7
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `fct_lump` from the `forcats` library

```
dat1 %>%
  group_by(fct_lump(Country, n = 3, w = Count)) %>%
  summarize(Count = sum(Count))
```

This should do it, also you can change the "Other" label using the `other_level` param inside `fct_lump`

Answer (score 5):

We could do this in two steps: first create a sorted data.frame, and then `rbind` the top three rows with a summary of the last rows:

```
d <- df %>% group_by(Country) %>% summarise(Count = sum(Count)) %>% arrange(desc(Count))

rbind(top_n(d,3),
      slice(d,4:n()) %>% summarise(Country="other",Count=sum(Count))
      )
```

output

```
  Country Count
   (fctr) (int)
1     AUS     6
2     JPN     5
3     USA     5
4   other     7
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(dat1)`), grouped by 'Country we get the `sum` of 'Count', then `order` by 'Count', we `rbind` the first three observations with the `list` of 'Others' and the `sum` of 'Count' of the rest of the observations.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat1)[, list(Count=sum(Count)), Country][order(-Count),
  rbind(.SD[1:3], list(Country='Others', Count=sum(.SD[[2]][4:.N]))) ]
#   Country Count
#1:     AUS     6
#2:     USA     5
#3:     JPN     5
#4:  Others     7
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
 d1 <- aggregate(.~Country, dat1, FUN=sum)
 i1 <- order(-d1$Count)
 rbind(d1[i1,][1:3,], data.frame(Country='Others', 
     Count=sum(d1$Count[i1][4:nrow(d1)])))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could even use `xtabs()` and manipulate the result.  This is a base R answer.

```
s <- sort(xtabs(Count ~ ., dat1), decreasing = TRUE)
setNames(
    as.data.frame(as.table(c(head(s, 3), Others = sum(tail(s, -3)))), 
    names(dat1)
)
#   Country Count
# 1     AUS     6
# 2     JPN     5
# 3     USA     5
# 4  Others     7
```

Answer (score 2):

A function some might find useful:

```
top_cases = function(v, top, other = 'other'){
  cv = class(v)
  v = as.character(v)
  v[factor(v, levels = top) %>% is.na()] = other
  if(cv == 'factor') v = factor(v, levels = c(top, other))
  v
}
```

E.g..

```
> table(state.region)
state.region
    Northeast         South North Central          West 
            9            16            12            13 
> top_cases(state.region, c('South','West'), 'North') %>% table()
.
South  West North 
   16    13    21

iris %>% mutate(Species = top_cases(Species, c('setosa','versicolor')))
```

Answer (score 1):

For those interested in the case for getting categories consisting of greater than some percentage placed into an 'other' category, here's some code.

For this, any values less than 5% go into the 'other' category, the 'other' category is summed, and it includes a label of the number of categories aggregated into the 'other' category.

```
othernum <- nrow(sub[(sub$value<.05),])
sub<- subset(sub, value >.05)
toplot <- rbind(sub,c(paste("Other (",othernum," types)", sep=""), 1-sum(sub$value)))
```