# Create an "Other" category by summing in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataset with ID's and a numeric value per ID. I require to show the top 10 of largest ID's and group the rest under an "Other" category.

I have researched [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35114679/7044446) question/answer but it works with counts instead of sums. So that approach wont work for my case

My desired result

```
ID          Value
63366849    42084408
63475529    21879648
6774736     21321888
91274582    17393328
63445915    15215002
1097911044  9926442
1095812405  8971332
1097910557  5388376
37548920    5114854
OTHERS      153587848
```

My data:

```
df=structure(list(ID= c("63366849", "63475529", "6774736", 
"91274582", "63445915", "1097911044", "1095812405", "1097910557", 
"37548920", "1005153076", "13513021", "51991938", "1010090155", 
"91265898", "91237574", "91344448", "1095956598", "28065538", 
"63341531", "63335642", "5637749", "17419836", "5567029", "5651301", 
"37839500", "63450446", "28424298", "29264885", "63328148", "63562603", 
"51702988", "7416450", "1005234045", "91520220", "91159937", 
"13801492", "9260536", "37722978", "63355924", "1098711718", 
"63443769", "60306461", "28485149", "2151526", "2127233", "1096063398", 
"27948572", "13834945", "27938888", "91179848", "41678031", "37837953", 
"91233367", "5557908", "28012681", "33446782", "91243709", "1007790961", 
"1095826946", "1095926858", "20189860", "24049724", "27903426", 
"28133395", "41446577", "37319481", "2033552", "27950302", "91200190", 
"91205127", "9527919", "1095303440", "13826841", "91218008", 
"63280472", "24074310", "37805433", "13801074", "28037341", "63353740", 
"1095793583", "1102371309", "1116493966", "2127316", "2153230", 
"37316948", "51778219", "5503745", "1099735096", "1222254600", 
"27786180", "2162536", "27964677", "2020408", "91349686", "37514200", 
"30208806", "1102351224", "28354311", "27929976", "63523710", 
"13838438", "28296329", "28410262", "28494063", "5721778", "91275248", 
"91353706", "37751608", "1097610166", "1098080648", "13810090", 
"63444976", "1221464992", "1097497475", "91100475", "1095312933", 
"28131889", "63506738", "7922341", "28238547", "27985819", "27958501", 
"23912889", "5707630", "1102388693", "24028654", "28128637", 
"5554160", "63369230", "36521093", "91525097", "27929902", "63441041", 
"1097919703", "40984557", "1097129811", "13843871", "63301433", 
"28236969", "37831774", "1000942168", "1005220322", "1098661759", 
"1095843775", "28399609", "37211106", "5683927", "28254346", 
"91268076", "28295325", "28496274", "13820294", "28354968", "37793321", 
"63495244", "63299126", "13849979", "63357743", "60262321", "1098753025", 
"91435400", "2195064", "63345546", "63251135", "13827671", "2007126", 
"40378506", "1097121371", "37828831", "5707059", "63324477", 
"1102644458", "37796841", "28334234", "28010824", "28495363", 
"27929493", "5558783", "51974763", "28296333", "63489129", "1102385538", 
"13814150", "13829893", "28377189", "91342964", "164497637", 
"52326169", "63286143", "1099738639", "63503298", "1097913686", 
"91070753", "37652636", "60352132"), Value= c(42084408, 
21879648, 21321888, 17393328, 15215002, 9926442, 8971332, 5388376, 
5114854, 5093730, 5004621, 3696756, 3424872, 3347432, 3337895, 
3105759, 3104409, 3056238, 2748870, 2738808, 2662730, 2555784, 
2268480, 2126700, 2051811, 2035200, 2025495, 1962000, 1926012, 
1829736, 1822980, 1657659, 1574901, 1546320, 1539355, 1480530, 
1456140, 1372302, 1372302, 1367235, 1350330, 1330560, 1327761, 
1289520, 1265556, 1258350, 1245060, 1228770, 1228545, 1209705, 
1196100, 1180533, 1175274, 1170286, 1144792, 1106820, 1106820, 
1080621, 1080621, 1080621, 1080621, 1080621, 1080621, 1080621, 
1080621, 1080264, 1067400, 1067400, 1003000, 993510, 992520, 
988560, 957408, 957408, 922350, 889893, 888300, 883800, 855150, 
835920, 833481, 833481, 833481, 833481, 833481, 833481, 833481, 
833481, 823458, 775300, 741420, 734760, 734760, 729882, 672660, 
666740, 631020, 621000, 621000, 600651, 598050, 553410, 553410, 
553410, 553410, 553410, 553410, 553410, 552690, 503340, 468120, 
439800, 416040, 415136, 403235, 398700, 383629, 383629, 383629, 
367380, 364941, 360207, 360088, 346680, 339582, 339201, 339201, 
339201, 339201, 303120, 300450, 289080, 282042, 238080, 234060, 
219531, 211300, 195447, 195447, 192960, 192960, 169000, 169000, 
169000, 163868, 163868, 156540, 143460, 136080, 132048, 127818, 
127818, 124920, 124920, 124920, 124920, 105120, 93690, 93690, 
77580, 66024, 64650, 62460, 62460, 62376, 58800, 58338, 57240, 
50524, 49260, 49260, 48240, 46528, 44100, 43110, 42930, 41640, 
40755, 38715, 37050, 35685, 33012, 30687, 28620, 28620, 24678, 
24570, 15189, 15120, 15120, 14504, 14310, 11424, 6000, 5940, 
5428)), row.names = c(NA, -196L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this, if I am understanding right.

Sort the `Value` column, keep the ID for the top 10, and then name the rest "Other". Then just sum over that new ID.

This shows the top 10 plus an "other" field. From your expected output, you might want `n = 9` instead.

```r
library(dplyr)

n <- 10

df %>% 
  arrange(desc(Value)) %>% 
  mutate(ID2 = if_else(row_number() <= n, ID, "Other"),
         SortOrder = if_else(row_number() <= n, row_number(), as.integer(n + 1))) %>% 
  group_by(ID2, SortOrder) %>%
  summarize(Value = sum(Value), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  arrange(SortOrder) %>% 
  select(ID = ID2, Value)

# # A tibble: 11 x 2
#    ID             Value
#    <chr>          <dbl>
#  1 63366849    42084408
#  2 63475529    21879648
#  3 6774736     21321888
#  4 91274582    17393328
#  5 63445915    15215002
#  6 1097911044   9926442
#  7 1095812405   8971332
#  8 1097910557   5388376
#  9 37548920     5114854
# 10 1005153076   5093730
# 11 Other      148494118
```

Answer (score 5):

A slightly cleaner option using the `forcats` package:

```
df %>%
  mutate(ID = fct_lump_n(factor(ID), n = 9, w = Value, other_level = "OTHERS")) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(Value = sum(Value)) %>%
  arrange(ID == "OTHERS", desc(Value))

# A tibble: 10 × 2
# ID    Value
# <fct> <dbl>
# 63366849  42084408
# 63475529  21879648
# 6774736   21321888
# 91274582  17393328
# 63445915  15215002
# 1097911044    9926442
# 1095812405    8971332
# 1097910557    5388376
# 37548920  5114854
# OTHERS    153587848
```

Comment: I was about to follow up on my own with something like this. My one tweak was going to be that if you `arrange(desc(Value))` before the mutate and use `fct_inorder(ID)` then the factors will be sorted after the summarize how you want it and have that preserved in the factor order for the future.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

arrange(df, desc(Value)) %>%
  split(c(rep("top", 10), rep("rest", nrow(.) - 10))) %>%
  (\(s) bind_rows(s$top, data.frame(ID = "Other", Value = sum(s$rest$Value))))
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 11 x 2
   ID             Value
   <chr>          <dbl>
 1 63366849    42084408
 2 63475529    21879648
 3 6774736     21321888
 4 91274582    17393328
 5 63445915    15215002
 6 1097911044   9926442
 7 1095812405   8971332
 8 1097910557   5388376
 9 37548920     5114854
10 1005153076   5093730
11 Other      148494118
```

(Data used:)

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("63366849", "63475529", "6774736", "91274582", "63445915", "1097911044", "1095812405", "1097910557", "37548920", "1005153076", "13513021", "51991938", "1010090155", "91265898", "91237574", "91344448", "1095956598", "28065538", "63341531", "63335642", "5637749", "17419836", "5567029", "5651301", "37839500", "63450446", "28424298", "29264885", "63328148", "63562603", "51702988", "7416450", "1005234045", "91520220", "91159937", "13801492", "9260536", "37722978", "63355924", "1098711718", "63443769", "60306461", "28485149", "2151526", "2127233", "1096063398", "27948572", "13834945", "27938888", "91179848", "41678031", "37837953", "91233367", "5557908", "28012681", "33446782", "91243709", "1007790961", "1095826946", "1095926858", "20189860", "24049724", "27903426", "28133395", "41446577", "37319481", "2033552", "27950302", "91200190", "91205127", "9527919", "1095303440", "13826841", "91218008", "63280472", "24074310", "37805433", "13801074", "28037341", "63353740", "1095793583", "1102371309", "1116493966", "2127316", "2153230", "37316948", "51778219", "5503745", "1099735096", "1222254600", "27786180", "2162536", "27964677", "2020408", "91349686", "37514200", "30208806", "1102351224", "28354311", "27929976", "63523710", "13838438", "28296329", "28410262", "28494063", "5721778", "91275248", "91353706", "37751608", "1097610166", "1098080648", "13810090", "63444976", "1221464992", "1097497475", "91100475", "1095312933", "28131889", "63506738", "7922341", "28238547", "27985819", "27958501", "23912889", "5707630", "1102388693", "24028654", "28128637", "5554160", "63369230", "36521093", "91525097", "27929902", "63441041", "1097919703", "40984557", "1097129811", "13843871", "63301433", "28236969", "37831774", "1000942168", "1005220322", "1098661759", "1095843775", "28399609", "37211106", "5683927", "28254346", "91268076", "28295325", "28496274", "13820294", "28354968", "37793321", "63495244", "63299126", "13849979", "63357743", "60262321", "1098753025", "91435400", "2195064", "63345546", "63251135", "13827671", "2007126", "40378506", "1097121371", "37828831", "5707059", "63324477", "1102644458", "37796841", "28334234", "28010824", "28495363", "27929493", "5558783", "51974763", "28296333", "63489129", "1102385538", "13814150", "13829893", "28377189", "91342964", "164497637", "52326169", "63286143", "1099738639", "63503298", "1097913686", "91070753", "37652636", "60352132"), Value = c(42084408, 21879648, 21321888, 17393328, 15215002, 9926442, 8971332, 5388376, 5114854, 5093730, 5004621, 3696756, 3424872, 3347432, 3337895, 3105759, 3104409, 3056238, 2748870, 2738808, 2662730, 2555784, 2268480, 2126700, 2051811, 2035200, 2025495, 1962000, 1926012, 1829736, 1822980, 1657659, 1574901, 1546320, 1539355, 1480530, 1456140, 1372302, 1372302, 1367235, 1350330, 1330560, 1327761, 1289520, 1265556, 1258350, 1245060, 1228770, 1228545, 1209705, 1196100, 1180533, 1175274, 1170286, 1144792, 1106820, 1106820, 1080621, 1080621, 1080621, 1080621, 1080621, 1080621, 1080621, 1080621, 1080264, 1067400, 1067400, 1003000, 993510, 992520, 988560, 957408, 957408, 922350, 889893, 888300, 883800, 855150, 835920, 833481, 833481, 833481, 833481, 833481, 833481, 833481, 833481, 823458, 775300, 741420, 734760, 734760, 729882, 672660, 666740, 631020, 621000, 621000, 600651, 598050, 553410, 553410, 553410, 553410, 553410, 553410, 553410, 552690, 503340, 468120, 439800, 416040, 415136, 403235, 398700, 383629, 383629, 383629, 367380, 364941, 360207, 360088, 346680, 339582, 339201, 339201, 339201, 339201, 303120, 300450, 289080, 282042, 238080, 234060, 219531, 211300, 195447, 195447, 192960, 192960, 169000, 169000, 169000, 163868, 163868, 156540, 143460, 136080, 132048, 127818, 127818, 124920, 124920, 124920, 124920, 105120, 93690, 93690, 77580, 66024, 64650, 62460, 62460, 62376, 58800, 58338, 57240, 50524, 49260, 49260, 48240, 46528, 44100, 43110, 42930, 41640, 40755, 38715, 37050, 35685, 33012, 30687, 28620, 28620, 24678, 24570, 15189, 15120, 15120, 14504, 14310, 11424, 6000, 5940, 5428)), row.names = c(NA, -196L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

One more tidyverse way

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  split(dense_rank(-.$Value) >= 10) %>% 
  map_if(c(F, T), ~ .x %>% summarise(ID = 'OTHERS',
                                            Value = sum(Value))) %>%
  map_dfr(~.x)

# A tibble: 10 x 2
   ID             Value
   <chr>          <dbl>
 1 63366849    42084408
 2 63475529    21879648
 3 6774736     21321888
 4 91274582    17393328
 5 63445915    15215002
 6 1097911044   9926442
 7 1095812405   8971332
 8 1097910557   5388376
 9 37548920     5114854
10 OTHERS     153587848
```