# How to group factors with low frequence into an 'other' factor in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe, dplyr, summary

```
# Generate counts table
library(plyr)
example <- data.frame(count(diamonds,c('color', 'cut')))
example[1:3,]

# Excerpt of table
       color  cut   freq
1      D      Fair  163
2      D      Good  662
3      D Very Good 1513
```

You can easily filter the table for freq > 1000 with: `example[example$freq > 1000,]`.  I would like to generate a table similar to this except where all the values which are less than a value e.g. 1000 are included in a row `(Other)` similar to what happens when you have too many factors and call `summary(example, maxsum=3)`.

```
     color         cut          freq     
 D      : 5   Fair   : 7   Min.   : 119  
 E      : 5   Good   : 7   1st Qu.: 592  
 (Other):25   (Other):21   Median :1204  
                           Mean   :1541  
                           3rd Qu.:2334  
                           Max.   :4884
```

---

**Example ideal output:**

Ideally I want to convert this  `example[example$color=='J',]`:

```
 color   cut freq
 J      Fair  119
 J      Good  307
 J Very Good  678
 J   Premium  808
 J     Ideal  896
```

and produce this:

```
 color       cut freq
     J Very Good  678
     J   Premium  808
     J     Ideal  896
     J   (Other)  426
```

**Bonus:**
If this kind of filtering is possible with ggplot to create a plot like below, but with this filtering, that would be great also.

```
ggplot(example, aes(x=color, y=freq)) + geom_bar(aes(fill=cut), stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this similar Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730067/creating-an-other-field

Comment: So what's your threshold for `Other` ?

Comment: @mtoto I don't mind the number exactly but I want the freq of 'cut' factors with less than the threshold to be grouped (by colour).  A threshold of freq < 500 maybe?

Comment: @docendodiscimus, thanks for the link, I'll have a look.

Comment: @amblina is the below what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative using `dplyr` to pipe the correct data directly into the `ggplot` call.

```
library(dplyr)
example %>% mutate(cut = ifelse(freq < 500, "Other", levels(cut))) %>%
  group_by(color, cut) %>%
  summarise(freq = sum(freq)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(color, freq, fill = cut)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Be sure to detach `plyr`, otherwise the output will be incorrect from the `dplyr` call.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
example <- data.frame(count(diamonds,c('color', 'cut')))


# Compute the row id where frequency is lower than some threshold
idx <- example$freq < 1000

# Create a helper function that adds the level "Other" to a vector
add_other_level <- function(x){
  levels(x) <- c(levels(x), "Other")
  x
}

# Change the factor leves for the threshold id rows
example <- within(example, 
       {
         color <- add_other_level(color)
         color[idx] <- "Other"
         cut <- add_other_level(cut)
         cut[idx]    <- "Other"
       }
)

# Create a plot
ggplot(example, aes(x = color, y = freq, fill = cut)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]